# Comparing 2 input fileds values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 html input fields, one in disabled and gets value from a php file using jQuery ajax and the other one is filled by the user.

I made a jQuery script which compares these two fields and should show a message if the user input is greater than the ajax filled input. The problem is that it returns a strange result, for example if the ajax field is 12300 and the input field is 8 it shows the message, but if ajax is 12300 and the input is 12229 than it does not show the message.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cantitate").blur(function(){
    var cant_ins = $("#cantitate").val();
    var cant_suger = $("#info_cantitate").val();
    if (cant_ins > cant_suger){
        $("#status_cant").text("Cantitatea depaseste disponibilitatea");
    }
        else
    {
        $("#status_cant").empty();
    }
        });
});
```

Comment: `.val()` from a input will return a string, not a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not numbers, that's why you get strange results, `1200` would be less than `200` as the first one starts with the character `1` and the second one with `2` etc.

You can use `parseInt` for integers or `parseFloat` for floats to parse the strings as numbers, or you can just use the `+` sign to coerce the strings to numbers

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cantitate").on('blur', function(){
        var cant_ins   = +$("#cantitate").val();
        var cant_suger = +$("#info_cantitate").val();

        if (cant_ins > cant_suger){
            $("#status_cant").text("Cantitatea depaseste disponibilitatea");
        } else {
            $("#status_cant").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: love the `+` syntax for coercing strings

Comment: @atmd it is actually "tricky" and will likely confuse people who have never seen it before, whereas `parseInt(value, 10)` would not likely lead to confusion.

Comment: @self - well, they've seen it now. There's actually more issues with `parseInt` as people tend to forget the radix and get strange results, but generally I would have used `parseInt` in an answer, but the OP isn't clear on wether or not the inputs only accepts integers, or if floats are allowed as well

Comment: @self true, but then the same could be said for Ternary operators or decision tables. every aspect of coding can confuse people who haven't seen it before.